# Adding (and) logic for a list of columns and generating feature

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have requirement to create a feature by checking the fields of two different dataframes.
df1 is a dataframe created from mysqldb and it will be static, the values of column(required) from df1 can be moved from True or False.

below are more details.

```
df1= 
flag    beta    required
alpha   A        TRUE
alpha   B        TRUE
alpha   C        FALSE
alpha   D        TRUE
```

```
df2= 
name    A   B   C   D   E   F
roy     1   1   0   1   0   0
john    0   1   1   1   0   0
sam     1   1   1   1   1   1
```

I trying to create feature alpha_flag by using the column name "beta" from df1 if the required column is TRUE.

So the code for alpha_flag will be like below

```
df2['alpha_flag'] = np.where(df2['A']==1 and df2['B']==1 and df2['D']==1 , 1 , 0)
```

The difficulty i am facing is to choose only the columns that are mentioned as required true from df1 and dynamically update my 'alpha_flag' creation condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can use boolean indexing to select the `beta` rows where `required` is `TRUE`, then check if these columns in `df2` is all equal with `1`

```py
df2['alpha_flag'] = df2[df1.loc[df1['required'].eq('TRUE'), 'beta'].tolist()].eq(1).all(axis=1).astype(int)
```

Note that if all `required` value is `FALSE`, this will cause selecting empty column from `df2` and lead to empty dataframe manipulation which might cause unexpected behavior, so a more robust version would be

```
cols = df1.loc[df1['required'], 'beta'].tolist()
df2['alpha_flag'] = df2[cols].eq(1).all(axis=1).astype(int) if len(cols) else 0
```